# Java: Find if the last line of a file is empty

Tags: java, file-io, line

I have a question about a school assignment I need to do it in Java. 
I need to load data from a file and check for errors in these files.

I read the file with a `bufferedReader` which works perfectly until the end of the file: it ignores the last line if that line is empty.

I know how to check for empty lines, but the last line simply doesn't give any result using the `readLine()` function of `bufferedReader`.

It's important that I know if the last line is empty as it must be. If the empty line doesn't exist, it should give an error.

So long story short, I need a way to tell the difference between the following situations (where `CRLF` is the end of the line):

**Situation 1 (correct):**

```
line x CRLF
line y CRLF
```

**Situation 2 (wrong):**

```
line x CRLF
line y
```

Both of these situations will return a null on `readline()` after line y.

I am counting the lines of the file on the way, so if I have a line counter (Note: that counter must count that empty line too, all the ones I found did not count them)

The files contain empty lines throughout too, if that should make any difference for the code I need (these lines are properly detected as they should be as the `EOF` isn't on these lines)

Note that the program works with or without that last line, it's purely that the assignment tells me to give an error if it's not there.

Comment: For the last line to empty you need to have `CRLFCRLF` at the end It appears you want to determine if the last line doesn't have a CRLF?

Comment: Isn't the definition of a line a series of characters terminated by a newline marker? What is an "empty" line? When you have read all lines, BufferedReader will return null.

Comment: BufferedReader won't tell you if the last line was terminated by a new line or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to determine if the last line has a CRLF you can read from the end.

```
public static boolean lastLineisCRLF(String filename) {
    RandomAccessFile raf = null;
    try {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
        long pos = raf.length() - 2;
        if (pos < 0) return false; // too short
        raf.seek(pos);
        return raf.read() == '\r' && raf.read() == '\n';
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (raf != null) try {
            raf.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's not a Windows file I would just check for `\n`

Answer (score 1):

**There is no empty line in your "situation 1"**. The `CRLF` belongs to line y and after that, there is nothing (which is what `readline()` tells you too).
It's just that in an editor, this `CRLF` tells the cursor to go one line down, so it looks like a new, empty line there, but in fact that's just an 'optical illusion' caused by the editor interpreting the characters `CR/LF` as a hint to show the cursor in a new line.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
    strLine = tmp;
}

String lastLine = strLine;
```

This would give you the last Line of the file. Why not check if the last line is empty or not ?